# Error when attempting to view the review stack

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Over the last couple of days I've been getting the following error when attempting to view any of the review stacks. (Using Chrome 25 on Windows.)

> An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.

[image: An error occurred when loading the review item]

**EDIT:** I should add that it was only the Webmasters review stack that resulted in this error. I was able to review on SO and other stacks without issue. When this problem occurs I get the following "error" under the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools.

[image: Error in Network Tab of Chrome Developer Tools]

And the corresponding HTTP Headers for this request:

[image]

## Now Resolved

I should add that this now appears to be resolved - I no longer get these errors - although I have done nothing more my end to aid this. As mentioned in the comments below, I had previously deleted the cache and some cookies, but this did not help. (I've not even restarted the browser in this time!)

Comment: Will ping mod chat - thank you for report.

Comment: Just to add... Sometimes when there is a new item to review in one of the stacks. eg. in "Low Quality Posts" there was 1 earlier, and I reviewed it OK. But the "Close Votes" are currently showing 12 and I get this error when trying to view them. Plus all the other stacks show this error (but there are currently 0 entries in these stacks at the moment.)

Comment: Hhhmmm... there might be a problem with my browser?! Using Chrome 25. It works OK on my Android phone.

Comment: does firebug report anything funky?

Comment: Hey, can I get you to open up the "Network" tab in Chrome's dev tools and try to reproduce? Send a screenshot of anything that pops up there, particularly if it has a funky status. Thanks! P.S. also check the console.

Comment: @Shog9: I have updated my question with screenshots from the Network/Headers in Chrome Dev Tools when this error occurs (oops, didn't check the console). However, the problem now appears to be resolved - I no longer get this error - but I have done nothing more my end to resolve this?!

Comment: Kinda hard to diagnose then, I'm afraid... If you encounter it again, try to capture an error in the network log somewhere - that might help lead us to the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at the end of my question, this problem now appears to be **resolved** and has not recurred.

(I'm answering my question, as the *Community* user appears to have bumped the question to the top of the active question stack - I guess because it had no upvoted/accepted answers?)

Answer (score 1):

Silly answer but I assume you cleared your cookies :)

As you know Chrome automatically updates so most of us are using builds on version 25... and im not getting any problems on win7 64&32... Try reinstalling it I would

Comment: I had cleared the cache; which didn't change anything. And I have since deleted all cookies related to Webmasters; which didn't help either (I was reluctant to delete _all_ my cookies). I should add that it was only the Webmasters Review stack that seemed to have a problem; I was able to review on SO and other sites OK. Anyway, the problem appears to have been resolved and I have done nothing more at my end(?) - I've not even closed the browser in this time!?